# Changing a Plone newsfeed's item's publish date

Tags: plone

Is there a way to change a newsfeed item's publish date in Plone? I have a Plone 4.1 instance. We weren't doing it right and had one item with lots of news in it. I broke them up into separate items but they are no longer ordered chronologically.

I know there is a contents tab and it appears you can reorder there by dragging one item around. However it does not stick.

I don't see anyway to do it in the ZMI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RSS feed uses the effective (or publishing) date, falling back to the modified date, for the `<dc:date/>` tag.

Give your content a correct effective date to correct the date in your RSS feed, see `Edit` -> `Dates` -> `Publishing Date`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a try tomorrow when I can access the machine again.

Comment: Your advice was correct! Thanks! The Plone interface is a bit confusing because it won't show the article dates sorted by article date, but when I viewed items in the newsreader after changing the dates they were ordered correctly.

Comment: @Mark: That is because the Plone UI is not your RSS reader; Plone can show items in manual order or in publication order too, but your RSS reader usually takes the Publication Date from the feed by default (it makes more sense for RSS readers to do so).